# XML findall is stopping at the first find

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse out XML using python 2.7 and xml.etree.ElementTree.

It works only for the first element in the tree and does not iterate over all of the other tags it should be capturing.

Below is the loop I am using to traverse the XML.

```
prefixes=['conn','dummy']
for datasource in root.findall('.//datasource'):
        for relation in datasource.findall('.//relation'):
            if 'connection' in relation.attrib:
                if relation.attrib['connection'].startswith(tuple(prefixes)): 
                    sql = SQL(relation.text)

                    if sql.isCustom() is True:
                        return sql.findTables()
                    else:    
                        print(relation.attrib['table'])
                        return relation.attrib['table']
```

The XML looks something like this.

```
<datasources>
    <datasource>
        <connection>
            <relation connection="conn.dbe" table="table1">
    <datasource>
        <connection>
            <relation connection="conn.abc" table="table2">
```

I have tried using iterall as well as findall('.//*relation') as a matching pattern but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Well, you are returning when `relation.attrib['connection'].startswith(tuple(prefixes))`, on both the `if` and `else` of the `sql.isCustom()` test.   If your problems runs deeper than that, you should post a [mcve], including actual and expected output.

Comment: Also, what's up with the three year dry spell for accepting answers?

Comment: Because the answers have come in a year after I asked them for the most part and I had already moved on.

Comment: And as for the question, my confusion comes why it works for only the first instance and not the rest in the document.

Comment: If you're not getting useful answers in less than a year timeframe, then you've really got to improve your questions.   For example, here you've failed to provide a [mcve].   You should return to your old questions and accept the helpful answers.  If you want faster answers, improve your questions by reading [ask] and [help] for starters, and adding a MCVE here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was only getting the first table was that I was returning after finding it, thus never completing the loop.